# Why is my ng-repeat not showing pulled data?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I am following an Angular [tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angularjs-get-started/table-of-contents) where I am trying to format my code in John Papa's [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) for Angular 1.

I am currently trying to display a table of github repos from any username that is inputted into the search form. Everything else displays except for the repos.

Please find a link to the code on plunker.co -> [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJsKeiSBdpuylMnOWWBJ?p=preview).

This is the html template code below:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController as github">
  <h4>{{ github.user.name }}</h4>
  {{ github.error }}
  <img ng-src="{{ github.user.avatar_url }}" title="{{ github.user.name }}" />
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select ng-model="github.repoSortOrder">
    <option value="+name">Name</option>
    <option value="-stargazers_count">Stars</option>
    <option value="+language">Language</option>
  </select>
  <label>Order By:</label>
</div>

<table class="col">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Stars</th>
      <th>Language</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="'repo in github.repos | orderBy: github.repoSortOrder'">
      <td>{{ repo.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ repo.stargazers_count | number }}</td>
      <td>{{ repo.language }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<a href="#/main">Back to search</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });
</script>
```

And this is the UserController js code:

```
// Code goes here

(function() {
  angular
    .module('app.github')
    .controller('UserController', ['github', '$routeParams', '$log', function UserController(github, $routeParams, $log) {

      var vm = this;

      var onUserComplete = function(data) {
        vm.user = data;
        github.getRepos(vm.user)
          .then(onRepos, onError);
      };

      var onRepos = function(data) {
        $log.info('getting data');
        vm.repos = data;
        $log.info('finished getting data');

      };

      var onError = function(reason) {
        vm.error = "Boo! Could not fetch the user data!";
      };

      vm.username = $routeParams.username;
      vm.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count";
      github.getUser(vm.username).then(onUserComplete, onError);

    }]);

}());
```

Lastly, this is the 'github' service as a dependancy to the controller:

```
(function() {

  angular
    .module('app.github')
    .factory('github', ['$http', '$log', function github($http, $log) {
      var getUser = function(username) {
        return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
          .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
          });
      };
      var getRepos = function(user) {
        $log.info('starting getRepos()');
        return $http.get(user.repos_url)
          .then(function(response) {
            $log.info('ending getRepos()');
            return response.data;
          });
      };

      return {
        getUser: getUser,
        getRepos: getRepos
      };

    }]);

})();
```

May I have someones input in this please?

Thanks

AlvSovereign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrapped in single quotes which angular will evaluate as a string:

```
<tr ng-repeat="'repo in github.repos | orderBy: github.repoSortOrder'">
```

It needs to be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="repo in github.repos | orderBy: github.repoSortOrder">
```

Comment: Also, github.repos doesn't exist. The variable name is repos

Answer (score 1):

The error is on the first line. You bound the controller to only that div.

```js
<div ng-controller="UserController as github">//here
  <h4>{{ github.user.name }}</h4>
  {{ github.error }}
  <img ng-src="{{ github.user.avatar_url }}" title="{{ github.user.name }}" />
</div>
```

Putting a div around the whole thing should fix this. Along with the ng-repeat mistake mentioned below by @robj.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. Yes I see now! Newb mistake! It all works fine now.

Comment: @AlvinSovereign your welcome, no worries. Happens to the best of us.